# How do I join my two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I have two Tables and I am trying to do a join or union to bring over one column from the second table.

```
SELECT Services,Metric_Type,services_be,Services_Be_L2,Services_Be
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.SERVICES_BE = table2.SERVICES_BE
```

`Metric_Type` is all I need from `table2`

Potential joins

**Table1**

```
Services_Be,
SALES_NODE_LEVEL1,
Fiscal QT,
Fiscal YR,
```

**Table2**

```
Services_Be,
Sales_L1 = SALES_NODE_LEVEL1,
Fiscal QT,
Fiscal YR
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your current query? What are the results, and how they differ from what you expect?

Comment: The column Services and Metric_Type  are not present in the two table ..where are these columns?.

Comment: current query isnt running for some reason Mustaccio and Scais Edge the Metric_Type only lives in the second table

Comment: If you have a column `Metric_Type` in `Table2`, please edit your post and add it there. Why did you think it was OK not to list it? How about `Services`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Services,Metric_Type,services_be,Services_Be_L2,Services_Be
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.SERVICES_BE = table2.SERVICES_BE
```

Looks like a valid join and that would allow you to use columns from both tables side by side.  The one thing that you may want to use are table aliases to make it easier to reference the table and then specifically identify the table your column is from in the Select list something like:

```
SELECT t1.Services,t1.Metric_Type,t1.services_be,t2.Services_Be_L2,t2.Services_Be
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.SERVICES_BE = t2.SERVICES_BE
```

If you want to `APPEND` the records from one table to another you will want to use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT 
    Services_Be,
    SALES_NODE_LEVEL1,
    Fiscal QT,
    Fiscal YR
FROM
    Table11

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    Services_Be,
    SALES_NODE_LEVEL1,
    Fiscal QT,
    Fiscal YR
FROM
    Table12
```

When appending, the column definitions and data types need to be the same between the top table and bottom.  `UNION ALL` will append every record from `Table2`, while `UNION` will only append records that are not already present in `Table1` (Sort of like `DISTINCT`).

Comment: Union doesnt work even when I inserted NULL values as dummy columns and when I am doing a join regardless of type of join I am doing I either get the Metric_type and nothing else or everything but null for metric_type.

Comment: Are you wanting to append the data? Are you using just Union or UNION ALL.  If UNION you may need to handle the null's as many times nulls are not compared how you think they might be.  Are you getting a specific error, can you edit the question and post the code you tried so we can look directly at it to give feedback on?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a column ambiguously defined error.
In the select statement, you list the field SERVICES_BE which belongs to both tables, and the sql parser don't know which table you meant.
try using table alias.

```
    SELECT t1.Services,t2.Metric_Type,t1.services_be,t1.Services_Be_L2,t1.Services_Be
    FROM table1 t1 
Inner JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.SERVICES_BE = t2.SERVICES_BE
```